# How do I combine more than one row of results based on a unique identifier

Tags: sql

I have the following table of data:

```
number  holiday
123456  LDN
123456  NYC
123456  IRL
456789  NYC
456789  CHILE
```

Basically each number can have up to 4 holidays; I need each number to only be displayed once, and then combine the holiday results into one field (rather than 3 in the example above for number 123456)

Ideally I want the table to display the following:

```
number  holiday
123456  LDN, NYC, IRL
456789  NYC, CHILE
```

I can either output the results to Excel and maniplaute from there, or use sql and temp tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL then you can use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT number, GROUP_CONCAT(holiday)
FROM table1
GROUP BY number
```

If you are using SQL Server you can emulate GROUP_CONCAT by using the `FOR XML PATH` hack. See [this article](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html) for more details.

Comment: I use sql-server; I'll definitely make a note of that trick.  Incredible that they don't have a native way to do that yet.